# How to run scheme program in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, scheme

Just started to learn SICP (Structure and Interpretation of Computer Program). I installed mit-scheme compiler. I am able to run the interpreter by just typing scheme in terminal. I also have VSCode installed along with linting support for scheme.

Now I need to write, compile and launch the scheme program from VSCode.How do I do that. I dont need to debug line by line.   I am new to VS code.

PS: I can write program, edit it and check for lint errors. I am unable to launch the scheme compiler out of the box. I am missing some steps in editing few jsons to get this done.

PS PS: I prefer VSCode and I want mit-scheme to interpret/ compile my program. Do not want to use racket or code runner extension. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone who are here but left disappointed due to no answer, please give it a try with, https://repl.it/languages/scheme and https://rextester.com/l/scheme_online_compiler 
Nice alternatives to racket or mit-scheme!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Main menu->Terminal->Configure tasks
2. Create new task:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "run scheme",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "scheme",
            "args": ["<", "${file}"]

        }
    ]
}
```

3. Open file with scheme code
4. Main menu->Terminal->Run Task->run scheme

Answer (score 2):

on mac os with chezscheme

1. install chezscheme

```sh
brew install chezscheme
```

2. install `code runner` extension of vscode
3. setup code runner in setting.json

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "scheme": "chez --script"
  },
```

4. run scheme

create `hello.ss`

```ss
; Hello World
(display "Hello World")
(exit)
```

click `run code` button in top right or menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most Scheme systems do not compile. They are interpreters. That is the reason why the book is called Structure and **Interpretation** of Computer Programs. The typical interaction with an interpreter is the REPL, the Read Eval Print Loop. The easiest way to write Scheme code is to use an editor like Emacs and execute `run-scheme`. After that you can send any s-expression with Ctrl-x Ctrl-e from the editor to the interpreter. Emacs shows the result in the REPL window.

[image: Emacs Scheme REPL]

Comment: Geiser running within Emacs provides even better integration with and features than the REPL running directly under Emacs. It is an Emacs extension similar to use of SLIME with Common LISP. It adds significant features and functionality to the REPL running within Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

What a coincidence! I'm learning SICP too.

I'm on a Mac. My way of running scheme programs in VS code is `control+shift+` to open its terminal and the input `scheme > foo.sch`. (replace `foo.sch` with you file name).

And you can do this in the built-in `Terminal` app too, without VS Code.